# Corda persistent API

Tags: corda

I am reading the documentation about Corda Persistence https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html and I have several points that are not clear to me.

1. Am I right that data are persisted in parallel with vault storing. I.e. vault storage is not changed and new tables are being added to store data also.
2. When we use
   `cordaRPCClient.vaultQueryBy` method will it understand by itself what to use: vault or data persisted in the custom database tables?
3. How the choice is done when for example only part of the data are available in the tables? is there any way to tell Corda explicitly that persisted data should be used for the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the answers to your queries:

1. Yes, you are correct, new tables are created in the vault corresponding to your QueryableState. All states that are required to be persisted should implement the QueryableState interface.
2. Your states are stored as the normal binary format as well, thus `cordaRPCClient.vaultQueryBy` would always query the vault for the `ContractState`, not the `PersistentState`. You could, however, query the custom database table using a jdbc session/ jpa.
3. What part of the state is needed to be persisted is a call you make depending on your requirement. Persisted data could be queried using custom JDBC queries/ JPA. The vaultQuery API always works in `ContractState`.

Comment: Thank you very much Ashutosh! This is very helpful! Do you know by any chance if there is any documentation confirming the fact that cordaRPCClient.vaultQueryBy always query ContractState and not PersistedState?

Comment: All vaulyQuery method variations finally call the _queryBy method. It needs a parameter of type ContractState, which represents the state being queried

Comment: I checked the link you provided but I do not see explicit confirmation there that persistence is not used when executing vaultQueryBy method. On the contrary, I see following  text:
`The Vault Query API leverages the rich semantics of the underlying JPA Hibernate based Persistence framework adopted by Corda.`
So, I am confused.

Comment: What I meant was with vaultQuery you need to specify which state you are querying for, its always a ContractState not a PersistState (the persistent representation of a Queryable State i.e JPA Entity). Having said that if you have configured a PersistentState the vaultQuery could take advantage of it to filter results based in the fields of the PersistentState, however the result returned is always a ContractState.